# Handling cors in node and express

Tags: node.js, express, cors

My main `app.js` file looks like this

```
const colors = require("colors");
const path = require("path");
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const { notFound, errorHandler } = require("./middleware/error");
const connectDB = require("./db");
const { join } = require("path");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const logger = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");

const authRouter = require("./routes/auth");
const userRouter = require("./routes/user");
const s3Router = require("./routes/s3");
const requestRouter = require('./routes/request');
const notificationRouter = require("./routes/notification");
const convoRouter = require("./routes/convo");
const messageRouter = require("./routes/message");
const profileRouter = require("./routes/profile");

const { json, urlencoded } = express;

// socket connection
const { appSocket } = require("./socket");

connectDB();
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const server = http.createServer(app);
```

I am passing `cors` to `express` app instance and then passing it to `http.createServer(app)` But still I am getting this `cors` error.

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3001/auth/user' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

… which is what the `cors` middleware will default to unless you say otherwise in the configuration.

Specify your origin:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}));
```

… more complex approaches are [described in the manual](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuration-options).

Answer (score 0):

The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response is wildcard '*' by default while using [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) middleware.

So if you are getting this error then there can be 3 most probable reasons for this :

1. You are using some route which is used before cors middleware was applied.

```js
app.use("/",someRouter); // Using this route will give cors

// ...

app.use(cors());

// ...

app.use("/",otherRouter); // Using this route will work fine
```

2. Cors errors are sometimes miss leading i.e. suppose you are uploading some file large file and your server fails to handle such large file then also you may get cors or suppose your server crashes then also you may get that error.
3. Lastly this is the least probable error that you may have re-changed the cors in some route thus you are getting cors.

Your code for CORS seems fine to me please look for top 2 possibilities that may have occurred.

Comment: "The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response is wildcard '*' by default" — Yes, this is the problem

Comment: "You are using some route which is used before cors middleware was applied." — No. If that was the problem then the header would be missing and not have the wildcard.

Comment: "Cors errors are sometimes miss leading" — This one isn't.

Comment: "Lastly this is the least probable error that you may have re-changed the cors in some route thus you are getting cors." — It's only set in one place and it is wrong.

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted the question and actually skipped "not" in the question.